# How should I define a lambda in my method's arguments?

Tags: java, lambda, java-threads

Ι have the following custom Runnable:

```
class RandomSum extends Runnable {

   public void run() {
     float sum - 0;
     for(int i = 0; i<1000000;i++){
       sum+=Math.random();
     } 
   }
}
```

And I want to run it like that:

```
  RandomSum s =new RandomSum();
  s.retrieveCallback((sum)->{
    System.out.println(sum);
  });
  Thread thread = new Thread();
  thread.start();
```

But I do not know how I should define the method `retrieveCallback` in RandomSum that accepts a lambda?

Comment: Where do you want to execute the lambda in `RandomSum` class? Do you want to print the sum after the `for` loop?

Comment: Actually I want to pass the sum in a lamnda therefore yes I want to do it after the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `retrieveCallback` within `RandomSum` as follows:

```java
public void retrieveCallback(FeedbackHandler feedbackHandler) {
    int sum = ...; // Get the value however you like.
    feedbackHandler.handleFeedback(sum);
}
```

And then define this `FeedbackHandler` interface as:

```java
public interface FeedbackHandler {
    void handleFeedback(int sum);
}
```

Essentially what happens when you pass lambda `(sum) -> {...}` to `retrieveCallback` is:

```java
retrieveCallback(new FeedbackHandler() {
    @Override
    public void handleFeedback(int sum) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: IC A lambda actually is a sinlgle-method anomymous class right?

Comment: Yes, where it is important that only one method can possibly match the signature that you pass in. Note that `(int sum) -> {}` is also possible (specifying the type of the argument), and that a lambda that returns something can be either `(...) -> returnVal` or `(...) -> { ...; return returnVal; }`

Answer (score 1):

One possible *target type* of the lambda you've shown is a `Consumer`. Define a method `setCallback` accepting a `Consumer<Float>` and store it as an instance variable. Then invoke it after the `for` loop.

```
class RandomSum implements Runnable {
    Consumer<Float> callback;
   
    public void setCallback(Consumer<Float> callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    public void run() {
        float sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<1000000;i++){
            sum += Math.random();
        } 
        callback.accept(sum);
    } 
}
```

Caller side

```
RandomSum s =new RandomSum();
s.setCallback((sum)->{
    System.out.println(sum);
});
```

Or using method references,

```
s.setCallback(System.out::println);
```

Preferably you can pass the callback in the constructor.